# NativeScript: Why am I getting a 'duplicate resources' error when trying to build/run my project?

Tags: nativescript

I am very new to android development and recently started working on a mobile application.

The mobile app that I am working on was created 4 years ago, is in need of updating, and I recently updated these 3 components:

1. Nativescript CLI
2. Nativescript Core Modules
3. Nativescript Android runtime

as well as it's dependencies:

1. moment
2. moment-timezone
3. nativescript-appversion
4. nativescript-cardview
5. nativescript-dev-typescript
6. nativescript-dom
7. nativescript-drop-down
8. nativescript-intl
9. nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager
10. nativescript-loading-indicator
11. nativescript-localize
12. nativescript-master-technology
13. nativescript-modal-datetimepicker
14. nativescript-pdf-view
15. nativescript-plugin-firebase
16. nativescript-secure-storage
17. nativescript-theme-core
18. nativescript-ui-sidedrawer
19. tns-core-modules
20. validator
21. babel-traverse
22. babel-types
23. babylon
24. lazy
25. typescript

The app had no problems running prior to these updates, but as we expected, it currently does not build or run after these updates were completed.

The error I am getting is:

---

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.

  > [app/tns_modules/lazy-install/node_modules/semver/semver.browser.js] C:\Users\enicholson\Code\llu.app\platforms\android\app\src\main\assets\app\tns_modules\lazy-install\node_modules\semver\semver.browser.js        [app/tns_modules/lazy-install/node_modules/semver/semver.browser.js] C:\Users\enicholson\Code\llu.app\platforms\android\app\src\main\assets\app\tns_modules\lazy-install\node_modules\semver\semver.browser.js.gz: Error: Duplicate resources
  >   [app/tns_modules/lazy-install/node_modules/semver/semver.min.js] C:\Users\enicholson\Code\llu.app\platforms\android\app\src\main\assets\app\tns_modules\lazy-install\node_modules\semver\semver.min.js        [app/tns_modules/lazy-install/node_modules/semver/semver.min.js] C:\Users\enicholson\Code\llu.app\platforms\android\app\src\main\assets\app\tns_modules\lazy-install\node_modules\semver\semver.min.js.gz: Error: Duplicate resources
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Unable to apply changes on device: emulator-5554. Error is: Command gradlew.bat failed with exit code 1.

---

Does anyone have experience with this issue or a similar one that can offer a potential fix?

I have worked with another team-member and have tried a few of the recommended solutions online, such as:

1. Deleting the hooks, node_modules, and platforms folder. Next, removing the android platform and re-adding it.
2. Inspecting the logs, looking for anything unusual
3. Ensuring their were no issues with the environment using: 'tns doctor'
4. Checking for duplicate files

I am still actively looking for solutions online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer:

In this repo from the error message:

C:\Users\enicholson\Code\llu.app\platforms\android\app\src\main\assets\app\tns_modules\lazy-install\node_modules\semver

there were two files that were duplicates of two other files, however they had ".gz" as their extensions. I removed the two ".gz" files and the application built/ran properly.